# Is it possible to submit a PhD thesis based on published journal papers without spending years as a grad student? If so, what part of the world?

Tags: phd, thesis, degree

In what academic cultures is it possible to submit a doctoral thesis without being enrolled into a doctoral program?

What I mean is this: if I had some scientific journal papers and I assemble a dissertation out of it, can I submit it and organise only a defense and not a multi-year process with other duties?

Comment: Are you thinking of the sorts of things mentioned in this Q&A?: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44382/can-you-get-a-phd-based-on-work-or-life-experience

Comment: I think only the Jessop answer at that link is relevant, actually. But this seems rare. Is the question here theoretical, or something you are interested in?

Comment: Please define "being enrolled into a doctoral program". What this means will be different in different countries, if it applies at all.

Comment: Doctoral program: an organised course that has an entrance examination and includes duties on behalf of the participant. What I ask is this: if I had some scientific journal papers and I assemble a dissertation out of it, can I submit it and organise only a defense and not a multi-year process with other duties?

Comment: This process is known as PhD by publication in the UK but the process differs depending on the university. More information here: https://www.findaphd.com/advice/phd-types/phd-by-publication.aspx and an example from my own university: https://www.port.ac.uk/study/postgraduate-research/research-degrees/phd-by-publication.